# How to deal with login attempts coming from 1-127.0.01 and what does it means?

Tags: 7

Recently on my drupal 7 site happens that i find the admin account blocked. Looking to the flood table i see a lot of failed login attempts from ip "1-127.0.0.1". It's an external attack or something not working in my site? The fact that the ip the request comes from is 'localhost' is confusing me. In both cases, how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After attempt five login drupal block account automatically

1. Install the Flood module [flood_control](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control)
2. Enable the Flood module
3. Go to admin/settings/system/Flood control
4. Change the "Failed login (username) window" from 6 hours to None
5. Save

[Flood Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control)

> This project is intended to add an administration interface for hidden
>   flood control variables in Drupal 7, like the login attempt limiters
>   and any future hidden variables.

[Flood Unblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock)

> This module makes it possible for site administrators to remove
>   ip-adresses from the flood table, or to remove all ip-adresses from
>   the table depending on the event type.

[Different ways to reset Drupal admin password](http://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/different-ways-reset-drupal-admin-password)

[Protect site from flooding when user login is attacked...](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96110/protect-site-from-flooding-when-user-login-is-attacked-by-brute-force)

Comment: yes, but it's meaningless to stop a localhost ip. What to do when the ip is not really defined like this? And it is an external attack or something wrong in drupal going on?